# Outlook shows HTML as TEXT

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, outlook

I send email from my ruby on rails app. All email clients display fine my email (gmail, the bat, thunderbird etc) but not Outlook :(

In outlook i see this:

```
my message text

--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
Content-Type: multipart/related; charset=f-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=f-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

my email text message

--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
Content-Type: text/html; charset=f-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

my email html code (<h1>test</h1><table...)

--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c--
```

Whats wrong???

Just in case headers from outlook:

```
Message-Id: <4e514d88.100fdf0a.403c.31a7@mx.xxx.ccc>
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=D0=97=D0=B0=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81_=D0=B4=D0=BB=D1=8F_=D0=BC=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B4=D0=B6=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B0_=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=BC=D0=BF=D0=B0=D0=BD=D0=B8=D0=B8_?=
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
User-Agent: Rails Application
X-Mailer: Rails Mailer
Return-Path: admin@xxx.ccc
X-Yandex-Forward: 8a20ef6ffc7eeb7ef7c8d000508718e0
```

**The same email from gmail, where all display good both for text and html mode:**

```
Delive
Message-Id: <4e514d88.100fdf0a.403c.31a7@mx.xxx.com>
Subject: xxx
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
User-Agent: Rails Application
X-Mailer: Rails Mailer
X-Yandex-Forward: 8a20ef6ffc7eeb7ef7c8d000508718e0


--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

email text 


--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
Content-Type: multipart/related; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline


--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

email text (plain text)

--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline


email text(html)

--mimepart_4e514d8786c25_d59..fdab8042069c--
```

Comment: What's the point of the empty multipart/related alternative on top? I don't think it's legal to send a part of type multipart/* without defining an inner separator for it and giving it a terminating line.

Comment: Also `charset=f-8` is not known by the IANA charset registry.

Answer (score 3):

How did you construct this mail? Did you add the headers manually?

I don't know *where* that ***charset=f-8*** comes from, but it's a bug and it renders that whole header line containing the `Content-Type: text/html` part invalid. You just got lucky the other mail clients didn't feel like being very strict there.

The invalid header line causes Outlook to interpret the part as plain text, which is rather sensible.

If you didn't add those headers manually, and ActionMailer got cheeky in stead, please post some of the code where you construct the mail. Might be worth posting another question.

Answer (score 1):

(1) multipart structuring in your sample is wrong; you need to achieve hierarchy like this (with proper transfer encoding and other details):

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="LEVEL0"

--LEVEL0
Content-Type: text/plain; ...
email text...

--LEVEL0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="LEVEL1"

--LEVEL1
Content-Type: text/html; ...
<html><body>...

--LEVEL1
Content-Type: image/jpeg; ...
...

--LEVEL1--

--LEVEL0--
```

(2) Some Outlook versions will not display HTML message directly when Content-Disposition: inline header is explicitly set for "text/html" part of it.